# Replace backslashes in string

Tags: ruby, string

I need to halve all backslashes.

```
body = '\\u001F\\x8B\\b\\u00003g#\\\\\\u0002\\'
```

I need output like this:

```
'\u001F\x8B\b\u00003g#\\\u0002\'
```

I tried this:

```
body.gsub("\\\\\\", "\\")
\\ -> \ (ok)
\\\\ -> \\ (ok)
\\\\\\ > \ (not ok)
```

I've read that ruby somehow parses string twice, maybe its somehow connected with my undesired output. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `.gsub('\\\\', '\\')`? See https://ideone.com/RXaX6M

Comment: Your desired output is not a valid string literal. The final quote is escaped, and the string's quote is not closed.

Comment: It is also not clear what you mean by your attempts with three listed outputs. What does each version mean?

Comment: The thing that ideone (etc.) not printing all backslashes. Your .gsub('\\\\', '\\') makes \\\\ -> \ (just one)

Comment: I just pasted part of long string and cuted it somewhere for example. Yeah, it might be not valid, just did it to show.

Comment: You are mistaken about what you have and what you are doing. ``body = '\\u001F\\x8B\\b\\u00003g#\\\\\\u0002\\'`` is actually a ``\u001F\x8B\b\u00003g#\\\u0002\``  string. When you use ``.gsub('\\\\', '\\')`` you replace each ``\\`` with ``\``, so the result is as expected, ``\u001F\x8B\b\u00003g#\\u0002\``. If you really have double backslashes, you would have defined it as a heredoc, see https://ideone.com/oUD07V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped this text into eval and it returned exactly what I wanted. Yeah, it’s not secure, but there are no solutions found so far

```
eval("\"#{body}\"")
```

Answer (score 2):

Likely what's happening, is you're printing the string with `p` or using `inspect`, and printing the string normally, will give you what you're expecting.

```
body = '\\u001F\\x8B\\b\\u00003g#\\\\\\u0002\\'
p body #> "\\u001F\\x8B\\b\\u00003g#\\\\\\u0002\\"
puts body.inspect #> "\\u001F\\x8B\\b\\u00003g#\\\\\\u0002\\"
puts body #> \u001F\x8B\b\u00003g#\\\u0002\
```

If you're using IRB, simply typing the variable name calls inspect automatically, e.g.

```
irb(main):001:0> body = '\\u001F\\x8B\\b\\u00003g#\\\\\\u0002\\'
irb(main):002:0> body
=> "\\u001F\\x8B\\b\\u00003g#\\\\\\u0002\\"
```

In other words, the string likely already is formated how you're wanting, you're just not seeing it without inspection info.

Answer (score 1):

Your output string is not valid. I think what you are looking for is:

```
body.squeeze("\\")
```

[Squeeze](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/squeeze) replaces the occurrence of multiple consecutive characters into a single character and returns a new string.